# Problems setting up NodeMailer with MailGun

Tags: azure-web-app-service, mailgun, nodemailer, ghost-blog

I'm trying to set up NodeMailer v0.7 in an Azure App Service for my Ghost blog. No matter what I do, I cannot get it to send mail when the exact same configuration is working in another environment.

It keeps telling me *Relaying Denied*. I've written up an extensive troubleshooting support page on this if anyone would like to help me.

I would GREATLY appreciate any help you can provide.

https://www.notion.so/Azure-Web-App-Ghost-Blog-Email-Issue-ef9221fde09d47e29a211ea45357563e

Answer (score 0):

On Azure App Service, for sending email, the recommended way is to use SendGrid or O365.

Due to some reason for SMTP, I think you can not directly use nodemailer to send mail on Azure WebApp, please see the blog [`Troubleshooting SMTP issues/Sending emails from Azure Web Apps`](https://blog.brooksjc.com/2018/09/18/troubleshooting-smtp-issues-sending-emails-from-azure-web-apps/) from a MS Support Engineer to know, and the first Q & A explains your current issue, as below.

> **1. Are you using a Relay Service or are you trying to send email directly from the web application?**
>
> If you are not using a relay service to send email, you are in an
>   unsupported scenario within all of Azure (including running an
>   application in a VM or cloud service). To reduce the possibility of
>   customers using Azure resources to send SPAM emails we do not allow
>   sending email directly from any service in Azure. See the blog below.
>   Relay services include SendGrid, O365, other third-party relay
>   services, and customer’s own on-premises relay services. So first
>   verify if the customer is using a relay service. If they do not have a
>   relay service they must configure their application to use one, there
>   is no other workaround.
>
> https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mast/2017/11/15/enhanced-azure-security-for-sending-emails-november-2017-update/

If you consider to switch to SendGrid, [@sendgrid/client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sendgrid/client) can help you to easier send mail.